# Writing git hooks to perform pull from bare repo to working repo

Tags: git

could anyone help me with this problem.
What I have done is I wrote a post-receive hook in a bare-repository to run hudson in my working copy

```
URL='http://192.168.1.1:8082/job/Jobforone/build'
echo "Run Hudson build at $URL"
wget $URL > /dev/null 2>&1
```

When I push from other remote computers to the bare repository in the 192.168.1.1(local server) hook is executed and hudson build is run in the working copy of the 192.168.1.1(local server) but the problem is working copy of 192.168.1.1 has not yet been updated until git pull is executed. So the hudson build runs on the same copy again and again(which makes no sense). So could anyone help me how could I write the hook that would perform pull on the local working copy and then perform the hudson build (above code).

Comment: As mentioned (but not emphasized) in the answer below, it should be Jenkins (Hudson) that pulls the changes when it starts building (either using git plugin or by having appropriate command as part of the build recipe), not the hook. Otherwise the hook could touch the working tree while build is running producing inconsistent build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Jenkins (very close to Hunson). I set-up post-hook (on a Github), as soon as push happend it triggers my Jenkins. What Jenkins does is run `get fetch` to update and then builds! It never run on working copy as you described.

Check out your build settings, don't forget to enable `Git`.

Comment: Jenkins is not "very close to" Hudson, Jenkins is **new version of** Hudson, renamed due to trademark issues when the project left Oracle after they took over Sun.